# Finding minimal polynomial of an element in an extension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, minimal-polynomials

What is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt2 +\sqrt{2}i$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$.

I proceeded in the following way:

Let $x=\sqrt2+\sqrt{2}i \Rightarrow x^2=2+2i^2+4i \Rightarrow x^2=4i \Rightarrow x^4=-16\Rightarrow x^4+4^2=0$

So for the minimal polynomial (say) $p$ of $\sqrt2+\sqrt2i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ we have $p|x^4+2^4$.

How do I conclude that this is the minimal polynomial?

Comment: 1) Is it irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$? 2) Alternatively, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}\,i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i)$, which has degree 4 over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the best option is to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}\,i) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i)$. Clearly $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}\,i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i)$.

$$x=\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}$$
$$x-\sqrt{2}=i\sqrt{2}$$
$$x^2-2\sqrt{2}+2=-2$$
$$\sqrt{2}=\frac{x^2+4}{2}\in\Bbb{Q}(x)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}\,i)$$

So $i\in\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}\,i)$ too. Thus, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}\,i) \supset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{2}\,i)= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, i)$.
This field has degree 4 over $\Bbb{Q}$, because $[\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(i):\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]=2$ (to prove this notice that $x^2+1\in\Bbb{Q}[X]\subset\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})[X]$ the degree can be 1 or 2, but it cannot be 1).